# Unable to install karma on windows

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, testing, karma-jasmine

While installing karma in windows cmd using `npm install karma --save-dev` there is an error:

> C:\Users\acer pc\Desktop\mean\testingMean>npm install karma --save-dev
>   npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:76752
>   npm ERR! 0a5126b","tarball":"https://registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/-/bluebird-2.
>   npm ERR!                                                                      ^
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\acer pc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-08-20T07_47_15_460Z-debug.log

Comment: I believe, you can get useful information (exact issue) in log if there is any dependency need to install or something else. Then try to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try clearing the cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```